# How to use "paramconverter with API-Platform?

Tags: php, symfony, parameters, api-platform.com

How to implement or use paramconverter with Symfony API platform?

I want to use entity ID on the route and generate immediately an object, ready to be used in the controller.

I'm not using annotations on this project. Route configurations are in the YAML file.

```
resources:
    App\Meetings\Domain\Entity\Meeting:
        collectionOperations:
            invitation_response:
                method: 'POST'
                path: 'users/{id}'
                controller: 'App\Controller\User\IndexController'
                defaults:
                    _api_receive: false
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use a [decorator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html)?

E.g. if your controller is something like:

```php
class IndexController {

   public function __invoke(CustomClass $object) {
      // do your thing
      // return a Response
   }
```

You could build a decorator `CustomClassConverterController`

```php
class CustomClassConverter {

     protected $innerController;
     protected $em;

     public function (IndexController $controller, EntityManagerInterface $em) {
        $this->innerController = $controller;
        $this->em = $em;
     }

     public function __invoke($id) {

        $object = $this->em->getRepository(CustomClass::class)->findOne((int) $id);
        if (! $object instanceof CustomClass) {
           throw new NotFoundHttpException('Custom class ' . $id . ' not found');
        }

        return $this->innerController($object); 

     }
}
```

You'd need to add this configuration to activate the decoration:

```
services:
    App\Controller\IndexController: ~

    App\Decorator\CustomClassConverterController:
        decorates: App\Controller\IndexController
```